# Spring transaction rollback happens only first time

Tags: java, spring, transactions, quartz-scheduler

This is odd but I may be missing something here

I am using quartz to initialize the spring config xml. When I trigger the quartz job first time, the transaction gets rolled back when a Exception occurs. But when the same job is triggered again, the transaction is not rolled back for the same Exception.

I can see from the log that when the job is triggered first time, the datasource (jndi lookup of Sybase Jconnect 7 from Websphere datasources) is initialized (not second time).

Service Layer

```
@Transactional(value="transactionManager", propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public void saveInfo(
        List<Foo> saveData) throws Exception {

    try{

        myDAO.saveInfo(saveData); //data to rollback on exception. Works First time only :(
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        logBO.createActivityLog("Error Saving Data");
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Spring-config.xml

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
         <ref local="sessionFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have played around with all propagation settings REQUIRED/REQUIRES_NEW/without propagation.

DAO method does a bulk update (jdbcTemplate)

**EDIT**

During the first time, this line is logged

> J2CA0086W: Shareable connection MCWrapper id 4c384c38  Managed
>   connection WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl@6f5a6f5a 
>   State:STATE_TRAN_WRAPPER_INUSE  from resource mydatasource was used
>   within a local transaction containment boundary.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "txManager",defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
```

hibernate and datasource code :

```
    <!-- Hibernate Related Configuration. -->

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.9:5432/dbname"/>
        <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="password" value="pwd"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.domain"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and txManager :

```
<!-- Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="txManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

don't forget to add line :

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.domain"/>
```

in sessionfactory, due to this so many times problem occur.

Comment: Thanks! But this prevents by service class to even load. The thread just hangs and nothing happens after the datasource initialization.

Comment: Can You show me your datasource code in xml ? with connection property.

Comment: @ArunChristopher - I have updated the answer check your xml like this and update if necessary and got any problem or error, post me.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. But the issue seems to be with having multiple transaction managers in spring config. I cant explain the reason why, but having multiple transaction managers (I have tried combinations hibernate tm- hibernate tm, hibernate tm - DataSourceTM, WebSphereUowTM) fail to rollback on exception.